# How To Fit Heston Model To Stock Data Stochastic Volatility Model

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, finance, stochastic-calculus

The stochastic volatility model known as the Heston model can be expressed in Mathematica in the following way

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/HestonModel.html

Define the Ito process of the correlated two‐dimensional Wiener process:

```
cW[ρ_] :=  ItoProcess[
             {{0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[2]},
             {{w1, w2}, {0, 0}},
             t,
             {{1, ρ}, {ρ, 1}}
           ];
```

Define the Heston model by SDEs driven by the correlated 2D Wiener process:

```
hm = ItoProcess[{
 \[DifferentialD]s[t] == μ s[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
   Sqrt[r[t]] s[t] \[DifferentialD]Subscript[w, s][t],
 \[DifferentialD]r[t] == κ (θ - r[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + ξ Sqrt[r[t]] \[DifferentialD]Subscript[w, ν][t]},
 {s[t], r[t]}, {{s, r}, {Subscript[s, 0], Subscript[r, 0]}}, t,
 {Subscript[w, s], Subscript[w, ν]} \[Distributed] cW[ρ]
];
```

Simulate the model using the stochastic Runge–Kutta scheme:

```
td = BlockRandom[
      SeedRandom[1988]; 
      RandomFunction[
        hm /. {μ -> 0, κ -> 2, θ -> 1, ξ -> 1/2, ρ -> -1/3, Subscript[s, 0] -> 25, Subscript[r, 0] -> 1.25}, 
        {0, 1, 0.005}, 6, 
        Method -> "StochasticRungeKutta"]
     ];
```

Visualize paths:

```
Row[{
 ListLinePlot[td["PathComponent", 1],  PlotLabel -> "Price of the asset"], 
 ListLinePlot[td["PathComponent", 2],  PlotLabel -> "Volatility of the asset"]
 }, Spacer[20]]
```

In this example I had to input values for the parameters of the Heston model. But lets say I don't know what the parmaters are before hand. Lets say all I have are daily close prices of stocks, the type of stock data that Mathematica provides.

How can I fit the parameters of the Heston model, and I suppose stochastic volatility models in general to stock data in a similar way I can fit the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck Process to stock data using EstimatedProcess[...]

If I try to use only EstimatedProcess

I first define the following function

```
HM[\[Mu]_, \[Kappa]_, \[Theta]_, \[Xi]_, \[Rho]_, SO_, R0_] :=ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]s[t] == \[Mu] s[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
  Sqrt[r[t]] s[
    t] \[DifferentialD]Subscript[w, s][t], \[DifferentialD]r[
   t] == \[Kappa] (\[Theta] - 
     r[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[Xi] Sqrt[
    r[t]] \[DifferentialD]Subscript[w, \[Nu]][t]}, {s[t], 
r[t]}, {{s, r}, {SO, R0}}, t, {Subscript[w, s], Subscript[w, \[Nu]]} \[Distributed] 
cW[\[Rho]]];
```

I then call this stock data

```
Table[data[j] = QuantityMagnitude[
Normal[(FinancialData[(index1 = {"NYSE:GPS"})[[j]], 
    "AdjustedClose", date = {{2000, 1, 1}, {2022, 1, 1}}])[
  "Values"]]];, {j, 1, 1}]
```

Then I apply EstimatedProcess

```
EstimatedProcess[data[1], HM[\[Mu], \[Kappa], \[Theta], \[Xi], \[Rho], SO, R0]]
```

It gives an this error

"The input data {27.3241,26.1446,25.0045,27.9531,29.2899,30.1548,31.0984,31.4129,30.9411,30.0762,<<3511>>} should be a vector or a matrix of real numbers or a valid TemporalData object."

Alternatively, I go back to the original definition of hm I had earlier, but then redefine td as the following

```
TD[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_] := BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1988];RandomFunction[
hm /. {\[Mu] -> a, \[Kappa] -> b, \[Theta] -> c, \[Xi] -> 
   d, \[Rho] -> e, S0 -> f, r0 -> g}, {0, 1, 0.005}, 6, 
Method -> "StochasticRungeKutta"]];
```

and then apply EstimatedProcess

EstimatedProcess[data[1], TD[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]]

and receive the same error.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that you have already tried using `EstimatedProcess` with your parametric `ItoProcess` and some data. What went wrong? Please include the data, the code you tied, and a description of what went wrong.

Comment: I thought EstimatedProcess only work with built in functions. It also works for stochastic process I define myself?

Comment: It would be worth a try! If it doesn't work straight away, then perhaps it might give errors or warnings that may lead you to a more focused question, or to finding a solution for directly.

Comment: @MarcoB I went and added to the question the result if I try to use EstimatedProcess.

Comment: This won't solve all your problems, but you can at least move forward by feeding a `TimeSeries` directly to `EstimatedProcess`: `findata = 
 FinancialData[{"NYSE:GPS"}, "AdjustedClose", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2022, 1, 1}}]; EstimatedProcess[findata, HM[\[Mu], \[Kappa], \[Theta], \[Xi], \[Rho], SO, R0]]`. This won't work yet, but it gives a different error :-)